# Find values of $n$ such that $n(n+2)(n+3)$ is a multiple of 8

Tags: probability, combinatorics, number-theory

So I was doing this question in which I have to find values of $n$ which satisfy the condition that $n(n+2)(n+3)$ is a multiple of 8 and n is a 2-digit number **(Let this be question A)**.

Earlier I had solved a similar question in which I had to find values of n such that $(n+2)(n+3)$ was a multiple of 3 **(let me call this question as question B)**. There I had used the fact that product of every 3 consecutive natural numbers was a multiple of 3!, so among every 3 groups of $(n+2)(n+3)$ I.E. $2\cdot3,3\cdot4,4\cdot5$ etc, only two groups will give the answer. So among the 99 groups possible, **two-thirds** of them will give me the answer so I got 66 as the answer. But here I am listing out cases and trying to find a pattern here. It might be an issue if the number might be large such as 39.

P.S. I have already solved question **A** using the long method of writing down cases and observing that among every 8 groups, 5 groups will give me the answer. So for 90 groups, I will get $\frac{90\cdot5}{8} = 56$ solutions.

Is there any way of solving either of questions **A** or **B** using combinatorics or probability?

Am I correct to think that, if $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)=24k$, then in how many ways can I choose $(n+1)$ such that the product of the remaining numbers is $8k$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's combinatorics inasmuch as all counting problems are combinatorics.

If $n$ is even, then $n+2$ is also even and one of them must be divisible by 4, so that's enough to make the product divisible by 8.  If $n$ is odd, then the product is divisible by 8 if and only if $n+3$ is.  So that winds up to being that the product is divisble by 8 if and only if the remainder from dividing $n$ by 8 is in $\{0,2,4,5,6\}$.  That will be over half of the two-digit numbers.

Comment: Oh ok, so among the 90 possible values that $n$ takes, 45 will be even and all of those will be accepted and from the 45 odd numbers, $(n+3)$ varies from $[13,102]$ so the number of multiples of $8$ in this range are 11, so the answer matches with 56. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If $8\mid abc$ then evidently also $8\mid (a+8)(b+8)(c+8)$.

This indicates that it is enough to solve the problem in $\mathbb Z_8$.

Then by brute-force (only $8$ checks to make) we find that it works for $n=0,2,4,5,6$.

Comment: "This indicates that it is enough to solve the problem in Z8" - I didn't understand this line. I am assuming by Z8 you mean the set ${0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}$. Can you explain your answer a little bit more, your method is somewhat distinct and I would like to learn this as well. Thanks

Comment: $\mathbb Z_8$ is not the set $\{0,1,\dots,7\}$ but is actually the set of equivalence classes $\{[0],[1],\dots[7]\}$ where e.g. $[3]$ stands for the set $\{3+8n\mid n\in\mathbb Z\}$. If for integer $P(n)$ denotes that $n$ has the property that $n(n+2)(n+3)$ is a multiple of $8$ then we have:$$P(n)\iff \forall k\in[n]\;P(k)$$ Since $\bigcup_{n=0}^7[n]=\mathbb Z$ we can restrict ourselves to checking only for the numbers $0,1,\dots,7$.

Comment: Oh ok but that IS what i had done initially by writing out cases. For $n$ belonging to $[10,99]$ , among every $8$ consecutive values(I.E. the $8$ remainder classes that any number belongs to on division by $8$) $5$ will satisfy the given condition. Next you only have to do $\frac{5\cdot90}{8}$ to get $56$. This is not exactly different from what I had done.

Comment: Okay. You can see my answer as a sort of formalization of your proof.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for explaining why the whole observation works :)